# LoadRunner does not Record the Events of Localhost

Tags: proxy, loadrunner

I'm using LoadRunner 2021 with Edge as the browser. LoadRunner can record all the events and generate scripts but fails when the url is based on "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

Moreover I checked the "HTTP Properties/Advanced/Proxy recording settings/Use the LoadRunner Proxy to record a local application" in "Recording Options" because I failed to disable the DEP for the browser is a 64-bit application (the poped warning) and I found in Internet that turning on the LoadRunner Proxy is a workaround for disabling DEP.

I'm wondering if it is the LoadRunner Proxy that causes the problem. If so, what can I do to make the record not exclude the loopback address?

Answer (score 1):

I am confused.  Only a single user would ever hit localhost.  That means you can answer your scalability question by measuring response time with and automated functional testing tool.